# What is This esc_html_e() i wordpress php?

Tags: php, functions, loop, 404-error

why do developers use

```
<?php esc_html_e() >?
```

in 404 pages, what does it mean, how does it works?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a combination of [`_e()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/), which echoes a translatable string, and [`esc_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html/) which is for outputting text so that the text is not interpreted as HTML.

You would use it to prevent HTML being smuggled into a translation and breaking your markup or causing security issues.

For example, if your theme had:

```
_e( 'My translatable string', 'my-text-domain' );
```

Then it's possible for a translation for `'My translatable string'` to be something like `'<script>alert('Bad!');</script>'`. If you don't use `esc_html_e()` then that script will be executed. If you use `esc_html_e()` then it won't be, because the `<` & `>` characters will be escaped as `&lt;` & `&gt;`, which out output as < and > and not interpreted as HTML tags.

Comment: All above said is correct I'd like to add a few links for you to further educate yourself (Google and - most of all - the Codex are your friends by the way):
This is a good read on sanitizing data: https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data
This is on the other part of the subject, translations (the whole Theme Handbook is extremely useful):
https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/